# "Cannot utime: Bad file descriptor" when upgrading ubuntu 8.04 to 10.04

Tags: ubuntu

After running `do-release-upgrade --proposed` on my Ubuntu Server 8.04, I got the message:

```
The upgrade is completed but there were errors during the upgrade process.
```

Searching up the upgrade output, I found this:

```
Setting up tar (1.22-2) ...

tar: ./md5sums: Cannot utime: Bad file descriptor
tar: ./control: Cannot utime: Bad file descriptor
tar: .: Cannot utime: Bad file descriptor
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
dpkg-deb: subprocess tar returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/diff_1%3a2.8.1-18_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/diff_1%3a2.8.1-18_all.deb
Exception during pm.DoInstall():  E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Could not install the upgrades

The upgrade is now aborted. Your system could be in an unusable
state. A recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a).
```

Apparenly, this is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tar/+bug/539814). More details are [here](http://www.pubbs.net/201001/debian/4925-re-problem-on-dpkg-unpack.html) and [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=563726#66).

I will post the workaround I found as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, you can create a wrapper for `tar` that will add the `--touch` option:

create a file named `tar` under `/usr/local/sbin` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/tar --touch -"$@"
```

Do:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/tar
```

Now run `aptitude dist-upgrade` to continue the upgrade process.
Delete this file after installation has completed.

Comment: this is probably chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/tar

Comment: You saved me from being stuck with my hosting provider's old Ubuntu template. +1

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the /usr/local/sbin/tar trick doesn't work. 
But I found this option helped for me. Run

```
export TAR_OPTIONS='--touch'
```

Then continue with your

```
apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error, and I couldn't install anything with `aptitude` either because of tar being broken. I had to leave `/usr/local/sbin/tar` so that `aptitude` would continue to work correctly.